# Elasticsearch match_phrase returns all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm using match_phrase query to match a phrase with a distance between them (slop) and my query returns all documents.
Match_phrase is just one part of my query, but the other one (term) performs ok on its own.
Just starting with Elasticsearch, my suspicion is because we turned off _source on an instance level (we don't store original documents) it doesn't work. 
I use .NET client to connect to Elasticsearch, but I don't think that's the problem

Here it is:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "doc.Alias.entityId": {
              "value": "EA::UNBOUND"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "doc.Alias.key": {
              "type": "phrase",
              "query": "Morgan Page",
              "slop": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/7wEHbG96

Comment: played a bit with lucene.net - if you don't store a field value, your document is matched, but you can't get the value to display it

Comment: but that still doesn't explain why specifiying slop doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Wait, what's your problem now?  That this query matches all the documents in your index?  Or that slop isn't working the way you expect?